# Issue with folder permissions

Tags: permissions

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. After finding out that my webhost allows incoming traffic on port 80 and 443, I decided I'd try setting up my own wordpress site. I'm using Ubutu server 16.04lts. The site is up and running and I can access it.

I'm now trying to get SFTP set up but I'm getting a bit confused with folder permissions.

I created a group sftpaccess and added my account to it. I then changed the ownership on the /var/www the webhost folder with the following command:

```
chown root:sftpaccess /var/www
```

I then also changed the permission on it again with:

```
chmod 770 /var/www
```

and

```
chmod g+s /var/www
```

But after doing so I cannot access the folder with a user in the sftpaccess group getting a permissions denied error.

If I change chmod 770 to 775 I can access the folder. My question is why, from what I'm reading the last digits place is for the "world" and being part of the group with 7 should give me access correct? My user being in sftpaccess should let him view the folder shouldn't it?

Sorry if this is a really simple question. Here is my output.

```
thearchitect@ubuntu-lampstack:/var$ cd www
-bash: cd: www: Permission denied
thearchitect@ubuntu-lampstack:/var$ ls -ld www
drwxrws--- 3 root sftpaccess 4096 Dec 27 21:20 www
thearchitect@ubuntu-lampstack:/var$ groups thearchitect
thearchitect : thearchitect adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare sftpaccess

sudo chmod 775 /var/www
thearchitect@ubuntu-lampstack:/var$ cd www
thearchitect@ubuntu-lampstack:/var/www$
thearchitect@ubuntu-lampstack:/var/www$ ls
html
```

Comment: Did you log in after adding yourself to `sftpaccess` ?  The changes will not apply to shells already running at the time you changed group membership.

Comment: please log out and log in again to see changes take effect.

Comment: Oh my gosh i'm and idiot. Thank you user4556274, forgive me I just started using linux like 2 weeks ago. Need more coffee. TYTY...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These awesome folks answered the question in comments. Thanks guys.

> Did you log in after adding yourself to sftpaccess ? The changes will
>   not apply to shells already running at the time you changed group
>   membership. – user4556274 4 mins ago
>
> please log out and log in again to see changes take effect. – George 1
>   min ago

Comment: Wont let me close for 2 days it says. Thanks again guys.